# Lost my left ALT-key

Tags: keyboard-layout, 14.10

I have upgraded my Ubuntu (from anno dazumal) to 14.10 and lost the standard behaviour of <kbd>Alt</kbd> key of my old account. The left <kbd>Alt</kbd> are now a ISO_Level3_Shift.

A new made account have a correct <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

1. I have tried to find what (old) config file that results in this change of keyboard configuration. I removed almost all .-files and files in .config I could find. (no luck)
2. I have reconfigured the keyboard using `xmodmap` and a local `~/.xmodmap`-file.

   keycode  92 = ALT_L Meta_L ALT_L Meta_L

Gives me an <kbd>Alt</kbd> that can activate HUD but combinations with other keys does not work such <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> etc.

I would prefer to find and remove the configuration that destroys my <kbd>Alt</kbd> key (1) rather than add a new configuration that alter the wrongful configuration (2).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably no one that [know exactly where the keyboard configuration is kept](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322). It depends if you have `ibus` set (by default yes), which `xkb` settings you have, and from the registry-under-another-name which has become the gsettings database.

Try to use `dconf-editor` and compare bits of configuration under the schema `desktop.ibus` and/or  `org.gnome.input-sources` --- a screenshot of the latter follows.

[image: dconf-editor for keyboard]

---

PD yes, I'm quite sad about the situation. International keyboard is mostly broken on Ubuntu since 13.04, plenty of bug reports around, and still not solved.

Comment: Thank you, i found the key that misconfigured the keyboard! I just had to set it to []

Comment: Which one das it? It would be nice to add it to the answer to help future readers....